# java need to match * with any character

Tags: java

I am new to Java so spare me. Below you can see my code. What it should do is read the 3th column from text file and if this column is S**ei or P***ei it returns the first word in that line. However my question is "How can I make * match any character from a to z"?. I heard of regular expressions but haven't really worked with them yet. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class moja {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("SloveneLexicon.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String vrstica;
            while ((vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                String s = vrstica;
                String[] dobi_besedo_v_vrstici = s.split("\\s+");
                String prva_beseda = dobi_besedo_v_vrstici[0];
                String tretja_beseda = dobi_besedo_v_vrstici[2];
                if (tretja_beseda =="S**ei"){
                    System.out.println(prva_beseda);
                    if (tretja_beseda =="P***ei")
                        System.out.println(prva_beseda);
                }

            }
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) (Hint `equals` rather than `==`)

Comment: `tretja_beseda =="S**ei"` :___(

Comment: Why the hell was this closed as duplicate? It's not about string comparison, it's about regex matching a string.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "read the 3th collum from text file and if this colum is S\*\*ei or P\*\*\*ei". Do you mean "If there is an asterisk '*' in the third column?

Comment: @Pimgd You're right, I reopened it.

Comment: Indeed. The string comparison issue was just a minor problem. To Rok Ivartnik: [Regular expressions tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: no if there is a string lets say Saaei or Sedei or Padvei, however as you can se S**ei needs to occour other 2  marked as * can be any characters from a-z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Pi[a-zA-z]{3}ei");
    if(p.matcher(input).matches()){
        This will work for 3 any letters (big or small)
    }
```

- "Pi[a-zA-z]{3}ei" // 3 letters big or small
- "Pi[a-zA-z]{1,3}ei" // 1-3 letters big or small
- "Pi[a-zA-z]+ei" // at least one letter
- "Pi[a-zA-z]*ei" // zero or more letters

Just remember to put your Pattern outside while loop, you should define it once and use many times

Comment: Glad I could help:) Good luck in improving your skills:)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at regex pattern matcher :

> manual : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Example :

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

Comment: The original problem statement seems to be "HOW CAN I MAKE * MATCHING any character from a - z", so their `"S**ei"` would be matched with `"S[a-z]{2}ei"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pattern matcher (e. g. [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)):

```
    if (tretja_beseda.matches("S[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]ei")) {
        System.out.println(prva_beseda);
    }
    if (tretja_beseda == "P[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]ei") {
        System.out.println(prva_beseda);
    }
```

`[a-zA-Z]` matches any character from a-z (case insensitive). I'm reading `SloveneLexicon.txt` in your code so I guess you'll also have to deal with slovenian characters (like `Č`). I'd suggest you to use `\\p{L}` (matching one unicode letter) instead of `[a-zA-Z]`:

```
    if (tretja_beseda.matches("S\\p{L}\\p{L}ei")) {
        System.out.println(prva_beseda);
    }
```

Second, your `if`-logic can not work since you nested the second `if` inside the first, but both conditions can't be true at the same time (String starting with `S` *and* `P`).

Third, I'd suggest you to program in english so you don't mix languages in your code making it easier to read; but that's of course up to you.

Comment: č is not a problem since there are no č,š,ž in treja_beseda

Comment: and how can mine if be both true at the same time since i am reading 1 line and only P**ei or S***ei can accour once in every line

Comment: The second `if` is only evaluated if the first `if` was true. Your code: `if (cond1) { code1(); if (cond2) { code2; } }`. Compare this: `if (cond1) { code1(); } if (cond2) { code2(); }`

Comment: hello if you can help me if (tretja_beseda.matches("S\\p{L}\\p{L}ei")) what would i have to put behind ei to have 0 or infinite word possible icludint š,č. Is this ok? (tretja_beseda.matches("S\\p{L}\\p{L}ei\\p{L}*"))

Comment: @RokIvartnik Yes, that would match all letters after `ei` (0..∞ times).